# JAVA ca-certificates error

Tags: java, dpkg

I try to install some things but i keep getting this error:

```
Error occured during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the JAVA virtual machine.
dpkg: error processing ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificate-java
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to first remove `ca-certificates-java`. After removing it you may need to reinstall your java.

Remove it completely using

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates-java
```

After it execute

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: After i execute `sudo apt-get install -f` i get same error.

Comment: @D3canas, execute `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst.bac` before the first command and re-execute both commands.

Comment: then i execute those without space between mv/var i get error: command not found then i execute with scape mv /var i get error: `mv: missing destination file operand after:/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst `

Comment: @D3canas the whole grayed line is single command . copy from `sudo` to  `postinst.bac` and execute it.

Comment: Still getting same error :( Maybe after removing certificates i should reboot or something?

Answer (score 2):

execute

```
dpkg --force-depends --configure ca-certificates-java
```

and solve other error appearing

Comment: Please provide some more information what the command does and how it solves the issue.